# UItextview Transparent Color IOS

Tags: ios5, uitextview, transparent

I want to set my UItextview s color transparent but not completely transparent. I want  little bit gray or black at the background exactly like the picture

[image]

I am using this code right now

```
 _textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

how can I make it transparent like in the picture above? Any example Code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
_textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
```

where alpha - parameter for transparent ( 50% in example).

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?  (You may need to experiment with the values).

```
_textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];
```